# dynamically choosing models for data binding (using a jQuery plugin via a directive)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I got the Spectrum jQuery plugin and two-way data binding to work, see the [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uA2BIyM1URmkd1jMokaH). Below is the code of my directive, as SO makes me paste some in...

```
app.directive('picker', function () {
return {
restrict: 'E',
require: 'ngModel',
link: function (scope, el, atts, ngModel) {
  el.spectrum({
    color: '#ffffff',
    flat: true,
    move: function (newColor) {
      scope.$apply(function () {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(newColor.toHexString());
      });
    },
    showButtons: false
  });
  ngModel.$render = function () {
    if (document.getElementById('firstColor').value !== "") {
      el.spectrum("set", ngModel.$viewValue);
    }
    };
  }
};
});
```

**What I have:**
I can choose a color using the Spectrum's color picker and it's in sync with an input field. I can also type a color into the input and it gets synced with the color picker.

**What I want:**
The thing is I want to choose multiple colors using the same color picker. Ideally the user clicks "choose 2nd color" button and then the sync is between the color picker and the second input field, it's turned off for the first field (it retains its value and can be turned back on via "choose 1st color").

How do I achieve that? For one color it works beacuse the color picker and the first input use the same ngModel.

I searched a lot and it doesn't look like I could change the value of the ngModel depending on the clicked button (or can I?).
Maybe I could use a variable in the $rootScope, but that would be a bad practice and actually so far I couldn't get the job done with it.

Do I have to use some watchers and controller injections or what? Honestly I don't know what to do next. All those options seem pretty complicated for something rather simple. The only thing I can do right now is to replace a color picker for one color with a color picker for another color but that’s rather primitive.

Comment: I believe having one color picker for one input is fine, as it keeps the code more manageable. I am not sure about your UI, seems to be similar to the date control that we attach to each input that takes date

Comment: @Chandermani I want one big color picker instead of two (or more) smaller ones.